# How to extract middle name from heterogeneous variable with different words count?

Tags: if-statement, sas

I am working in SAS and I have the following dataset from which I need help to  extract middle name from heterogeneous variable with different words count.

I saw prior [link](https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Programming/extracting-middle-names-from-a-variable/td-p/287941) but it does not work for me.
my dataframe named statisticians has only 1 variable

Full_name
Ronaldo Al Fisher

H. O. Meir Lee
Sara Kim Ivan
Marco Sina

Names with first and last names only should be blank in the new column called middle.
I tried the following code but it does not work:

```
data statisticians; length middle $10;   set statisticians;    if
count = 2 then middle=.;    if count = 3 then middle= scan(name,2);   
if count = 4 then middle=scan(name,2);  run;
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Howto separate Middle name from double given name and or double last name?

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions is what you're looking for. You might need to fiddle with it, or find one online that covers more cases. [regex101.com](http://regex101.com) is a good resource for testing them out.

```
data names;
  input Full_name $ 1-50;
  datalines;
Ronaldo Al Fisher

H. O. Meir Lee
Sara Kim Ivan
Marco Sina
;

data names_with_middle;
  set names;
  regex = prxparse('s/^(.+?\s+)(\w+)\s+(\w+)$/$2/');
  if prxmatch(regex, strip(full_name)) then 
    middle_name = prxchange(regex, 1, strip(full_name));
  drop regex;
run;
```

Results:

```
Obs   Full_name            middle_name
1     Ronaldo Al Fisher    Al
2  
3     H. O. Meir Lee       Meir
4     Sara Kim Ivan        Kim
5     Marco Sina
```